# meteor template.dynamic load data from session

Tags: forms, meteor, meteor-blaze

i have a page split in two: 
on left {{> expenseList }}
on right {{> Template.dynamic template="expenseForm" data=expenseData}}

on left its a list
on right its a form to enter elements in the list.

desired behaviour: 
1: form is empty and ready to add expenses
2: add an expense, form is cleared and ready for next
3: if i click on the left on the submitted expense from {{> expenseList }} the form is populated with the data of that expense and i can update that entry.

i cannot get it to work though. my form doesn't dynamically change the data. i tried to simplify code and add it below

the page code:

```
<template name="claimsPage">
   <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            {{> expenseList }}
         </div>
         {{> Template.dynamic template="expenseForm" data=expenseData}}
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

the page js

```
Template.claimsPage.helpers({
   expenseData: function() {
       var data = Session.get('expenseData');
       return data;
     }
});
```

the list js

```
Template.expenseList.events({
   'click a': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var data = {
      date: this.date,
      description: this.description,
      _id: this._id
   };
   Session.set('expenseData', data);
}
});
```

the form js

```
Template.expenseForm.helpers({
  purposes: function() {
   return Purposes.find();
  },
  expenseData: function(){
      return Session.get('expenseData')
  }
});
Template.expenseForm.events({
  'click #add-expense': function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var template = Template.instance();
      var expense = {
          date: template.find("[name='date']" ).value,
          description: template.find("[name='description']" ).value,
          purposeName: template.find("[name='purpose'] option:selected" ).value,
          _id: Random.id()
      };
      Meteor.call('addExpense', expense, function(error, result) {
           if (error)
              return alert(error.reason);
         template.find("form").reset();
      });
     }
});
```

the form html

```
<template name="expenseForm">
  <form>
  <input name="date" type="text" value="">
  <input name="description" type="text" value="">
  <select name="purpose">
    <option value="">Select a purpose</option>
    {{#each purposes}}
      <option value="{{this.purposeName}}">{{this.purposeName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
  <button id="add-expense" type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

I would really appreciate your help with this,
Thanks,
Cezar

Comment: what does your html look like for expenseList and what does the method "addExpense" do?

Comment: `<template name="expenseList">{{#each expenses}}<a><li>{{description}}</li></a></template>` is the list html. the addExpense does a Meteor.call to Expense.insert

Comment: the data appears now in the input fields. just can't get it to work with the selects. i cannot seem to insert selected into the <option>. i used a UI.helper: `UI.registerHelper('selected', function(key, value){
       return key == value ? ' selected' : '';
});` but `<option {{selected purposeName = "purposeName"}} value="{{purposeName}}">{{purposeName}}</option>` doesnt work.